# Remove entire joomla installation

Tags: joomla-3.x, phpmyadmin

After an malresearched update I have broken my joomla installation trying to push 3.2.7 to 3.3.6 as my server does not support the Php version required. Since I didn't keep backups as it is currently a test environment it would be easier for me to just reinstall from scratch.

Of all the questions using the words in the title their does not appear to be a question in regards to uninstallation of Joomla. To try an narrow this down so that it is not too broad do I simply just need to remove the folder where it was installed? So just the www directory if this server only had Joomla installed? Is there only the one database I need to remove from Phpmyadmin?

Running on a CentOS release 6.6 (Final) server. I have complete control of this machine.

Comment: Joomla 3.3 requires PHP 5.3.10, but if your server does not support this, then you should really consider changing your hosting provider. This is an old version of PHP which **should** be supported.

Comment: In a general sense this question seemed a good fit for the site. The server is owned by a collegue and I can do whatever I want with it. After all that was done in testing I want to start with a clean slate. I do plan on updating PHP but that wasnt the focus of my question. Other answers by you have gotten me where I am now so thanks all around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before reinstalling, delete the files and folders that have been installed into the www or public_html or other folder where Joomla is installed.

There is an option during the standard Joomla installation on the Database Configuration page to remove any existing tables so there's no need to drop (remove) the database tables using phpMyAdmin or similar.

Akeeba Kickstart has a similar option to drop (remove) existing tables if you are restoring from a backup.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just clear the installation folder and remove the database. If you intend to reinstall you only need to clear the files and tables, you can reuse the folder and database.